# organic group content not displaying

Tags: organic-groups

I enabled organic group example module. When I looked at my groups, none of the content belong to the group was displaying. It seem to be a filter error of some sort, but this is all straight out of example and it's not working.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: I have experienced similar kind of problem, I want to show all the group content shared within a group in a view. Just download [og_extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_extras) module, enable it and you will get amazing blocks and views including the one you wanted.